# Why do I get “Subscript out of bounds error”? in R

Tags: r

I'm trying to assign a certain quantity of computers from one big portion to a smaller portion of computers.

If I increase the number of computer types I don't get an error, but I want to have only one type of computers.

If a run the command below with `number_of_computer_types=1` (I get the error) 
if the `number_of_computer_types >1` (I do not get the error) 
command:

```
quantity_computers[nodeCount,] <- quantity_maincomputers[computerNode,]
```

When running a function in R:

```
computer_status <- initliaze_computer_status(num_nodes,number_of_computer_types)
```

I expect to be able to input one type of computers in my code and assign it to another portion of computers. for example, assign 5 Dell PC's from a total of 30 Dell PC's to a certain customer.

How can I solve this error?

Comment: Here is how to format code on stackoverflow.https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help . Also, With logical, you need to use == instead of just a =  . It is  same in almost all programming  languages . Maybe that is the issue here

Comment: When asking for help, you should include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

Comment: I tried to use == but it did not solve the problem,  The code I wrote is: if(n == computerNode){       
            computerNet <- computerNet %>% add_edges(c(nodeCount,computerNode))            
             quantity_computer[nodeCount,] <- quantity_computer[computerNode,] 

           }